# Get Firefox command line startup command of currently running instance

Tags: command-line, firefox

Is there a way to get the command which was used to open my currently running Firefox instance?

In Chrome there is `chrome://version/` where it is listed under Command Line. I couldn't find it in the **About** pages of Firefox.

Comment: `about:support` look for *Application Binary* ... oh, wait, you want the full command line don't you

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the full command with all flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows** : You can get the Details via "Task Manager" itself :

**(A)** Start "Task Manager" **(B)** Then go to Details tab **(C)** Here , right-click the column names at the top & Choose "Select Columns" to get a list of Available Columns.
**(D)** Here , you can scroll downwards to see "Command-line" , which you can enable.

**(E)** Back to "Task Manager" Details tab , you can scroll to FireFox Processes (there may be many)
**(F)** Check the new "Command-line" Column to get the Details you wanted.

**Linux/MacOS** : You can get the Details via `ps` command itself :

Open a SuperUser (root) terminal & execute `ps | grep -i firefox` command to get the Command-line you want.
You might have to give the Correct necessary OPTIONS to `ps` command , which you can get in the man Pages. It might be something like :
`ps -o args | grep ....`
`ps -o cmd | grep ....`
`ps -ef -o cmd | grep ....`
`ps -aef | grep -i firefox`
Depending on your OS , version variations , packages installed & other Details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, which compared to the other answers has the added benefits of a) being OS agnostic b) working when multiple instances of Firefox run concurrently.

[Enable the command line of the browser console](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html).

Now copy and paste the following snippet at the browser console and press Enter.

```js
(()=>{
  var i = 0; var args = [];
  do{
    var arg = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].getService(Ci.nsIEnvironment).get("MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_RESTART_ARG_" + i++);
  }while(arg != "" && args.push(arg));
  console.log(args.join(" "));
})();
```

Comment: I just gave it a try and got an error: “Uncaught TypeError: Services.env is undefined”.

Comment: Hm, I use Firefox Developer Edition (114.0b3), so I guess it *will* work soon on Firefox Release version.

Comment: Well, as far as I am concerned, I’m using Firefox ESR (102.11.0esr); there are many versions in between.

Comment: Fixed it! (tested with 99.0.1)

Comment: Works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you may find the command-line of any application by using
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Drag the bullseye icon over the Firefox window, and this will select
the matching Firefox process.

Double-click the process to see the full command-line.

Answer (score 0):

With [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) at least on Windows you can use the following oneliner:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like '*firefox*' -and $_.Parent -like '' } | ForEach-Object { $_.CommandLine }
```

I use `$_.Parent -like ''` in the oneliner to detect which is the parent process.
The other ⁎firefox⁎ processes that appear if you remove that, are the ones created by the parent process, -again- at least in Windows.

It is possible this oneliner work on [other operating systems with PowerShell installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/#powershell-0) as well but I haven't tested it.